# VueJS Fails to compile

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to vue.js and I'm trying to install vue.JS cli using npm.
Everything gets installed fine, even the npm run dev

But when I visit the webpage, I get a "Failed to compile error"

I've attached a snapshot of the error.

Please advice.
[image: Vuejs Failed to compile error]

Comment: did you run npm install? And you don't have to run your project in xampp, you can do it from (for example) your documents folder, the development server will run from there.

Comment: i did npm install. 
Let me move the project to a different directory, say documents like you suggested, i'd give you feedback

Comment: @Rienk Nope. It didn't work.
I even created a new project altogether in the documents folder, but same problem

Comment: It should work when doing this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli. Just create a new project and cd into it and run it. A problem may be your node and/or npm version

Comment: I was able to pull in an empty scaffolding for vue.js from a friend and it loads fine.
My Node version is 8.11.1
Vue is 2.9.3

Maybe it was the webpack-simple template  or probably my system's architecture (32-Bit) that the former one wasn't agreeing with

At least this new one works.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with this version of Prettier, make a downgrade with command bellow and re-run the project.

```
npm install --save-dev prettier@1.12.0
```